# Declaring my CellClass to extend to UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm simply trying to display a tableview of names in the array of Smiles that I have set up. I need to declare my cell class "ClubCell" to extend to UITableViewCell, how would I go about doing this?

```
class  SmileClub: UITableViewController {

var Smiles: [String] = ["Price Garrett", "Michael Bishop", "Tom Kollross", "Cody Crawford", "Ethan Bernath", "Alex Mlynarz", "Ryan Murphy", "Kelly Murphy", "Ryan Roshan", "Sean Ko"]


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ClubCell
{
    let cell: ClubCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClubCell") as! ClubCell!
    cell.Name.text = self.Smiles[indexPath.row] as String
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Smiles.count
}
```

Comment: Why did you just completely change your question? Don't do that. It leaves  the existing answers in a bad place. I simply stated you should add one line to your question, not delete the original question details.

Comment: BTW - See my updated answer. FYI - if you don't know how to extend a class in Swift then you should go back to the Swift book and study up on the basics for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method needs to be `UITableViewCell`, not `ClubCell`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: ClubCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClubCell") as! ClubCell!
    cell.Name.text = self.Smiles[indexPath.row] as String
    return cell
}
```

And make sure that your `ClubCell` class extends `UITableViewCell`.

It should be:

```
class ClubCell : UITableViewCell
```

Comment: I get an error on the "return cell" line when I implemented your suggestion.  

The error reads: Cannot convert return expression of type 'ClubCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: Does your `ClubCell` class extend `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: I'm a little new with this, and am not quit sure what you are asking.

Comment: Update your question with the declaration for your `ClubCell` class (the `class` line of your `ClubCell.swift` file.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to clear the errors, but now I'm getting a runtime/compile error when I select the SmileClub VC - I get a fatal crash and the error:
"Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10f43f490) to 'ToothSense.ClubCell'"

Comment: That's a whole new issue. Close out this one and post a new one with relevant details.

Comment: I have checked my class on the Storyboard too.  The Custom cell class is set to ClubCell, so I'm at a lost what could be the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ClubCell` is a subclass of UITableViewCell and it should look like:

```
class ClubCell:UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var Name:UILabel!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClubCell",forIndexPath:indexPath) as! ClubCell
     cell.Name.text = self.Smiles[indexPath.row] 
      return cell
}
```

In this line `cell.Name.text = self.Smiles[indexPath.row] as String` no need to downcast to String because your static array is already into String so change it to `cell.Name.text = self.Smiles[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Wow I am not ... my friend

Comment: At least explain your answer. What was wrong and was does your answer fix. Code-only answers are frowned up here.

Comment: I get an error on the "return cell" line when I implemented your suggestion, same as above. 
The error reads: Cannot convert return expression of type 'ClubCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell'